# How to get a fully unlocked version of Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-7

I am running on a corporate PC and I recently been given full admin access, however when I install Chrome it still has some of the features locked. For example I can't change my startup page or sign in to Google Chrome. It shows a message something like "Some settings might be managed by your administrator"

Comment: You forgot to mention your OS for the record

Comment: Are there possible domain-level policy settings in force? I think those would over-rule even admin rights.

Comment: Potentially. I don't know. But can't I like build my own Chrome install to bypass this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your computer is from work, there may be a separate administrator account that has some permissions that you do not. To find this out go to the start menu>click on your account picture>click manage user accounts>select your account and view the permissions.

Hope this helped!
-mars